# Destroy placeholders in 2 UITextViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have 2 UITextViews on a single View Controller. They have placeholders in each and I'm trying to get the placeholder to disappear when the textViewShouldBeginEditing. I've tried using tags, but the first one will work, then each selection after that fails to destroy the placeholders. Thanks

Comment: placeholder? in a textview? there isn't.

Comment: It would help if you could show all relevant code. The placeholder also automatically clears once you start typing.

Comment: I had to create NSMutableAttributedStrings for the place holders as they have '>' in them.

Comment: is there textField or TextView. UITextView doesn't have placeholder.

Comment: Do you want both to disappear when one textView is selected, or indiviually?

Comment: I want the placeholders to be empty  once the textview has been selected. So one at a time.

Comment: It's a TextView with NSMutableAttributedStrings in it. So 

self.textview.attributedText = self.NSMutableAttributedString

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted this post. Assigning UITextView with an attributedText gives it a place holder.

Comment: textView.text containsString, really is not a good way to handle this.  What if i type something with "enter" dismiss, and then reenter the textView.  Is that the same place you tried if  [textView is firstResponder()] instead of contains string?

Answer (score 2):

just do like this

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if([textView.text isEqualToString:@"Enter Text here......"]) //Enter Text here...... is your placeholder text
    {
        textView.text = @"";
    }
}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if([textView.text length] == 0)
    {
        textView.text = @"Enter Text here......";
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally I would do that. The issue for me is that they have different placeholders of NSMutableAttributedString types.

Comment: I also like putting this in shouldChange textInRange                                  if textView.text.length == 1 && text == "" {
   textView.attributedText = textView.placeHolder
   textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

I used

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

and it works fine now. Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score -2):

Use if textView.isFirstResonder, but do it in

```
textViewDidBeginEditing
```

not in

```
textViewShouldBeginEditing
```

Comment: This doesn't classify as an answer. If another answer is incorrect, state that it is so that it can be removed or fixed. The purpose is to provide clear correct answers for not only the OP, but also for any others who might have similar problems

Comment: That's not working either. I tried using tags and if tag = 1 else if tag = 2 and that fails as well.